# NGINX sub domain proxy pass

Tags: nginx

Version: nginx/1.2.0 || (I know the risks, its for a internal server) How would I setup a system where `17.hostname.com` would be put as proxy_pass `http://192.168.56.17:80` (Where 17 would be replaced with what ever number was before the hostname)

Comment: You should redeem using "solution" with `if`. See either http://serverfault.com/a/388660/67675 or http://serverfault.com/a/388709/67675

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The [regular expression server_name](https://serverfault.com/a/388660/115189) and [map directive](https://serverfault.com/a/388709/115189) solutions are better than this one, which uses the [evil if directive](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

The [$host](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) variable contains the hostname which the client requested, although you need to process this a bit to just get the part you want. It looks like the only way to achieve this is with the [if](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) and [set](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#set) directives from the Rewrite module, so try something like this:

```
server_name *.hostname.com;

if ($host ~* ^([0-9]+)\.hostname\.com$) {
    set $proxyhost 192.168.56.$1;
}

proxy_pass http://$proxyhost;
```

Comment: Im getting some errors when I try and use your method `2012/05/12 21:03:06 [error] 30314#0: *26 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 69.171.162.3, server: *.vm.hostname.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.56.106:80/favicon.ico", host: "106.vm.hostname.com"`
Ive setup proxy_bind to point to my local interface and its still giving me that issue

Comment: I should note that a ping to the same address from the same machine works fine

Comment: nginx is selecting the correct upstream, so that part seems to be working. Does this happen for all upstreams? Does `curl http://192.168.56.106:80/favicon.ico` from the server running nginx work?

Comment: Blind if() using is plainly wrong, it's *almost* deprecated, it's not good practice (not even mentioning "best" one).

Answer (score 5):

```
server_name ~^(?<subnum>[0-9]+)\.hostname\.com$;

proxy_pass http://192.168.56.$subnum;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Answer (score 5):

```
map $host $backend {

    default 1;
    ~*^(?P<number>[0-9]+)\.hostname\.com$        $number;

    # FIXME: [0-9]+ must be replaced to regex with accurate check 1..254 range
    # for example [1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4] or similar

}

server {
    server_name *.hostname.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.56.$backend:80;
    }

}
```

And remember: [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) !!! ;-)