# nginx: remove string in $host

Tags: nginx, rewrite

```
server {
    server_name *.com.another.com;
    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/$host;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
```

On above example, if someone make a request to `www.jaja.com.another.com`, nginx will look in directory `/var/www/html/www.jaja.com.another.com`

This is what I need: If someone make a request to `www.jaja.com.another.com`, I want nginx to look in directory `/var/www/html/www.jaja.com`

In other words, the `$host` is `www.jaja.com.another.com`. I need to remove `.another.com` in the `$host`

Nginx string replacement is new to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.*)\.another\.com$;
    root /var/www/html/$subdomain;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ { <...> }
}
```

Comment: It's better to leave the root directive in the [server context](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/388552/nginx-sub-domain-proxy-pass/388709#388709):

```
map $host $directory {

    default www;
    ~*^(?P<subdomain>[a-z0-9\-\.]+)\.com\.another\.com$        $subdomain;
}

server {
    server_name *.com.another.com;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/$directory;
        index  index.html;
    }

}
```